# decreasing random process depending on previous draw

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-walk, random-functions

I draw a number $x_i \in [n]$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I draw a number again $x_{i+1} \in [x_i]$. I repeat this drawing process till i got an 1. This generates a random sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^k$.
All draws are uniformly at random. 

Question 1: What is $P[x_i = 1] $ meaning the probability of stopping at a specific index i. 
Question 2: $P[x_i = k] $ where k is some number in N. 
I already solved Question 2 to some recurrence $\forall k > 1$: $s_{i,k}(n) = \sum_{l=k}^n \dfrac{1}{l} s_{i-1,l}(n) = P[x_i = k] $ with base case $s_{1,l} = \dfrac{1}{n}$. But its quite a messy way and not able to be in closed form so im wondering if anyone else has a better way of solving this.

Comment: You mean whether it is possible to write in closed form the quantity $$ \sum_{k \le k_1 \le n } \sum_{k_1 \le k_2 \le n} \cdots \sum_{k_{i-2} \le k_{i-1} \le n} \big(\prod_{ j = 1}^{i-1} k_j\big)^{-1} \frac{1}{n}$$ for any $k \in [n]$? I would guess that there is no simple closed formula, at least for the partial sums of the harmonic series. Sorry, I deleted the previous comment, because the formula was wrong.